# QGIS Extract Max value from polygon layer crossed by line layer

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon layer that was produced from a raster layer and the values manipulated to show dispersal effort in years, I.e. how far an animal could potentially move within one year of dispersal from a known site. On the image below this is the multicoloured lines.

I also have a line layer that shows the Least Cost Path (LCP) between different known sites. In the image this is the dark green line.

[image]

I want to extract the max value of 'years' for each LCP from the underlying polygon layer.In this image below the value assigned to the line that connects to the yellow star (top left) and circle (bottom right) should be 3 (The pale green represents 3 years).

I have no idea how to do this. There are more sites than just the two in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the polygon layer to a raster using the newly calculated field (dispersal in years) for the values. Then used the GRASS [v.rast.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/v.rast.stats.html) function.